# How to remove case insensitive query parameters with Apigee?

Tags: parameters, apigee

Using Apigee API proxy, my target endpoint is case-insensitive regarding accepting parameters. I'd like to strip out some parameters from the request, but how do I do that in a case-insensitive manner?

The [Apigee documentation](http://apigee.com/docs/ja/api-services/content/assign-message-policy) mentions:

```
<AssignMessage name="AssignMessage-1">
  <AssignTo createNew="false">request</AssignTo>
  <Remove>
    <QueryParams>
      <QueryParam name='apikey'/>
    </QueryParams>
  </Remove>
</AssignMessage>
```

Using this example, I also want to strip out `apiKey`, `APIKEY`, or any other case combination.

I tried doing it with JavaScript, but the parameters were NOT removed:

```
var apikey = 'apiKey'; // Found by looping through the parameters.
delete context.targetRequest.queryParams[apikey];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is the right answer. You can remove a query parameter using the following JavaScript code:

```
var apikey = 'apiKey'; // found by looping through the parameters
context.removeVariable("request.queryparam." + apikey);
```

See the [Apigee variables reference](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/api/variables-reference) for more information.